# USB Barcode Scanning in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, barcode, scanning

I have USB Barcode Scanner device and when I use this, it gives me products code.

I want this number in a variable or a JSON file to use it in my react project, but I can't make any relation with those two.

I want this, when QRCODE in database and QRCODE from device are equal, new items adds to cart

Problem is, I can't use QRCODE from USB Barcode Scanner and put it in a variable, I can't identify it